# Is it required to mention money returned by friend in ITR filing in India?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, gift-tax, borrowing

I live in India. For a long time I was giving money to my friend as he lost his job; there was no other option for income. But later he got job so he returned all my money recently into my bank account.

Do I have to mention this in my income tax return filing?

If so, how do I report it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best consult a CA. If the amount is less than Rs 50,000 it's not an issue. Any thing more the best way would have been to have a loan agreement. It can be done post facto as well.